# ionic ion option style and class not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Working with Ionic version 3.

html example:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming">
        <ion-option value="nes" class="tored" style="color:red"><span>NES</span> </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**My purpose is to change (CSS)** specific option values with style or class.

I tried to search here or from documentation for a solution but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for change the css based on a value you can use , ngClass or ngStyle 
[see this link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/styling-with-variables/122893)

```
[ngClass]="value==='yourValue'?'ClassA':'ClassB'"
```

and you can also review official docs for NgClass and NgStyle

Comment: No, I am not looking at this. Style and class element are not applied inside ion option.